# Retornar valor padrão caso não haja registro

Tags: postgresql

Possuo o seguinte comando sql de select:

```
SELECT 
    public.controleimpressoes.codigo, 
    public.impressoras.patrimonio, 
    public.impressoramodelo.modelo,
    public.impressoralocal.descricao,
   (select SUBSTR((to_char(data - interval '1 month', 'TMMonth')),1,3))dataMes,
    diferecacontador, 
    diferecacontadordigital, 
    diferencacontadorcolor,
    public.empresa.nome, 
    datainicial, 
    datafinal
FROM 
    public.controleimpressoes, public.impressoras, public.impressoramodelo,
    public.impressoralocal, public.empresa
where 
    public.controleimpressoes.codigoempresa = public.empresa.codigo and
    public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressora = public.impressoras.codigo and
    public.impressoras.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and 
    public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressoralocal = public.impressoralocal.codigo  and
    data between '2017-01-01' and  '2017-12-31'  and
    public.impressoras.patrimonio between '1000' and '1882' and
    public.empresa.nome between 'A' and 'B' and 
    public.impressoramodelo.modelo between 'C748' and 'C748' 
order by 
    public.empresa.nome, public.impressoras.patrimonio, data
```

E o mesmo me retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível ajustar essa query para que quando não houver registro no mes me seja retornado `0` como valor padrão?

Algo semelhante a isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde fevereiro não teria nenhum registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `generate_series` para gerar os números de 1 a 12 (meses) e a partir deles, buscar seus registros. Veja:

```
select
    g,
    to_char( to_timestamp(to_char(g, '999'), 'MM'), 'TMMon') as mes, 
    count(r.id) as qtd
from generate_series(1,12) g
left outer join registros r on extract(month from r.data) = g
group by g
order by g
```

**Dados de Testes:**

```
  create table registros
  (
  id int,
  data timestamp
  );

  insert into registros values (1,'2018/01/01');
  insert into registros values (2,'2018/01/01');
  insert into registros values (3,'2018/02/01');
  insert into registros values (4,'2018/02/01');
  insert into registros values (5,'2018/02/01');
  insert into registros values (6,'2018/04/01');
  insert into registros values (7,'2018/05/01');
  insert into registros values (8,'2018/06/01');
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloquei no [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c38f2/15)

> Você não precisa do `SUBSTR` para abreviar o mês, basta trocar `TMMonth` por `TMMon`

---

> Na outra resposta, está errado o `COALESCE(NULLIF(seuCampo,'') , '0' )`. As duas funções fazem a mesma coisa, bastaria: `COALESCE(seuCampo , '0')`

---

> A funcão `generate_series` também aceita `TIMESTAMP` como parâmetro, que no caso de meses, facilita =]

Referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html

---

**Edit:**

Para seu código, acredito que possa ficar assim (Não pude testar por não ter a estrutura das tabelas):

Basicamente, salva os dados que precisa em uma tabela temporária, depois faz um left join com a função:

> Houve mais solicitações pelo chat, e foram implementadas no código:

```
with dados as ( 
SELECT 
    public.controleimpressoes.codigo, 
    public.impressoras.patrimonio, 
    public.impressoramodelo.modelo, 
    public.impressoralocal.descricao, 
    data, 
    diferecacontador, 
    diferecacontadordigital, 
    diferencacontadorcolor, 
    public.empresa.nome, 
    datainicial, 
    datafinal 
FROM 
public.controleimpressoes, public.impressoras, public.impressoramodelo, 
public.impressoralocal, public.empresa 
where 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoempresa = public.empresa.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressora = public.impressoras.codigo and 
public.impressoras.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo and 
public.controleimpressoes.codigoimpressoralocal = public.impressoralocal.codigo and 
data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' and 
public.impressoras.patrimonio between '1000' and '1882' and 
public.empresa.nome between 'A' and 'B' and 
public.impressoramodelo.modelo between 'C748' and 'C748' 
), meses as (

Select distinct
    intervalo,
    d.patrimonio,
    d.modelo,
    d.descricao,
    d.nome
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::timestamp, '2017-12-31'::timestamp, '1 Month') as intervalo 
CROSS JOIN dados d)


SELECT DISTINCT
    to_char(intervalo , 'TMMon') dataMes, 
    m.*,
    d.diferecacontador, 
    d.diferecacontadordigital, 
    d.diferencacontadorcolor, 
    d.datainicial,
    d.datafinal
FROM meses m
LEFT OUTER JOIN DADOS d on date_trunc('month',d.data) = m.intervalo and m.patrimonio = d.patrimonio
order by m.nome, m.patrimonio, d.data
```

> Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria bem isso, mas não entendi muito bem como funciona essa função, tu poderia me ajudar a adaptar pra minha query?

Comment: a função retorna uma "tabela" com a sequencia de números informados. Há também a possibilidade de usar outros tipos de dados (date/ timestamp). Esses joins com vírgulas me quebram.... rsrs ficam muito embolado, mas vou tentar

Comment: de qual tabela vem a data ?

Comment: Da tabela `controleimperssoes`

Comment: veja se dá certo

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro Rovann: `function generate_series(unknown, unknown, unknown) is not unique`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74212/discussion-between-r-santos-and-rovann-linhalis).

Answer (score 0):

Se você se referindo a coluna, tente fazer assim:

```
COALESCE( NULLIF(seuCampo,'') , '0' )
```

O NULLIF compara se o campo passado no primeiro parâmetro é igual a vazio, e for ele coloca 0 no lugar do valor. Você substituir estas aspas vazia por qualquer valor, no seu caso acho que seria '0.0'.

Comment: Na verdade o que eu preciso é que mesmo quando ele não encontrar nada, por exemplo no mês de fevereiro, ele me retorne alguma coisa ainda, vou atualizar minha pergunta par ver se fica mais clara